# Time threshold as where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I've got this table:

```
+-----------------+------+----------------+------------+------------------+------+--------+
| date            | host | process        | text       | num1             | num2 | suffix |
+-----------------+------+----------------+------------+------------------+---       0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656871111 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656871111 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656871111 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656871111 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656871111 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656872222 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656877777 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656877777 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656877777 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656877777 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 23 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656877777 |    0 | mt     |
| Jul 29 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656877777 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 29 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656877777 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 29 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656877777 |    0 | dn     |
| Jul 29 09:24:16 | mmr  | mmr-core[1111] | Aweg3AOMTs | 1563866656877777 |    0 | dn     |
+-----------------+------+----------------+------------+------------------+------+--------+
```

From the table I need to find which num1 id has both suffix mt and dn. Which I with Gordon Linoff' help managed with this query:

```
SELECT num1
    -> from table4
    -> WHERE suffix IN ('mt', 'dn')
    -> GROUP BY num1
    -> HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT suffix) = 2;
```

Now the thing is that I need to find num1 which suffix 'dn' is arrived later than 72 hours or don't find the num1 if its dn didn't arrived until 72 hours...

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Just slight modification of the query

```
SELECT num1
FROM table4
WHERE suffix = 'mt' or (suffix = 'dn' and `date` > NOW() - INTERVAL 72 HOUR)
GROUP BY num1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT suffix) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation on the date/time values:

```
SELECT num1
FROM table4
WHERE suffix IN ('mt', 'dn')
GROUP BY num1
HAVING MIN(CASE WHEN suffix = 'dn' THEN date END) < MAX(CASE WHEN suffix = 'mt' THEN date END) + INTERVAL 72 HOUR;
```

You have multiple rows for `'dn'` and `'mt'`.  It is not clear if you want the mins or the maxes.  But this comparison givens you an idea of how to proceed.